# setSeparatorStyle on only 1 section

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview, tableview

How do I remove the separatorStyle for only 1 section. I have a grouped TableView and would like to remove the SeparatorStyle for only the first section, but keep it for the rest.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this

```
[_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

and then manually draw separators inside every cell.

That can be done in:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It's not elegant solution but it works.